# Эффект перелистывания страниц

Tags: android, java

Есть проект для андроид "android-page-curl" с эффектом перелистывания страниц с изображениями. Мне же надо вместо изображений - текст. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Тоже самое. Берете скрин своего view и применяете к этому скрину эффект листания.

Comment: Да, но мне надо большой текст, который не помещается на одной странице, надо сделать книгу apk.
App Book Maker не подходит.